# Drawing a perpendicular line to another line which is drawn parallelly from a point to another line

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I know it's a bit messy to describe, but I need to find an algorithm to provide me with the distance between two points, Only point we don't know is x5, and y5, Can you implement an algorithm that only includes other coordinates and some math stuff?? I am sending an example of my problem.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65791098/844416 - you need `nlen`

Comment: This is really a geometry question.

Comment: Yes, I am not an engineer and am not able to easily comprehend to create a formula, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is linked answer clear?

Comment: No, I require something like distance = slope^2 * x3 - y4 .... something like that, it is not about programming.

Comment: Answer gives all needed information for your data including formulas.   `it is not about programming` - OK, it should be closed

Comment: use vector math... define your line as start point `p0=(x3,y3);` and unit direction vector `dp=(x2-x1,y2-y1); dp/=|dp|;` now do perpendicular projection of `p=(x4,y4)` using dot product `(x5,y5)=p0+dp*dot(p-p0,dp);` no trigonometry is needed (the `dot` behaves like `cos(a)`)

Answer (score 0):

use vector math...

define your line as start point:

```
p0=vec2(x3,y3);
```

and unit direction vector:

```
dp=vec2(x2-x1,y2-y1); 
dp/=|dp|;
```

now do perpendicular projection of `p=(x4,y4)` using `dot` product:

```
vec2(x5,y5)=p0+dp*dot(p-p0,dp);
```

As you can see no trigonometry is needed (the dot behaves like `cos(a)`) so now the distance is:

```
dist=|p0-p+dp*dot(p-p0,dp)|
```

In case you do not need the `vec2(x5,y5)` and you want just the distance then in 2D you can simply dot product with perpendicular vector to `dp`...

```cpp
p0=vec2(x3,y3);
dp=vec2(x2-x1,y2-y1);  // direction vector
dp/=|dp|;              // unit
dq=vec2(dp.y,-dp.x);   // rotate it by 90 deg
dist=dot(p-p0,dq);     // distance between p0 and p in dq direction
```

by simply swap `x,y` coordinates of `dp` and negate one of them (which just determine if the `dp` is rotated CW or CCW by 90 deg). However note that such `dist` result can be negative (will tell you from which side of the line `(x3,y3),(x5,y5)` you coming from so if you need unsigned distance just use abs:

```
dist=|dist|;
```